# Can not connect to MongoDB cloud (ATlas)

Tags: java, mongodb

We are evaluating

We are trying to connect to MongoDB cloud (Atlas) from java app. but observing exception.

Configuration:

- Java test application running on Ubuntu box
- MongoDB hosted on MongoDB Cloud (atlas, cloud.mongodb.com)
- DB is configured as sharded clustered environment.

**Code**

```
MongoURI uri = new MongoURI("mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVERIP_1>,<SERVERIP_2>,<SERVERIP_3>/admin?replicaSet=EPCCAP-shard-0&ssl=true&authSource=admin");

SimpleMongoDbFactory dbF = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(uri);
DB db = dbF.getDb("capdb");
System.out.println(db.getCollectionNames());
```

**StackTrace:**

```html
Stacktrace : -
Jan 20, 2017 8:37:02 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[<SERVERIP_1>, <SERVERIP_2>, <SERVERIP_3>], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500, requiredReplicaSetName='EPCCAP-shard-0'}
Jan 20, 2017 8:37:02 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server <SERVERIP_1> to client view of cluster
Jan 20, 2017 8:37:02 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server <SERVERIP_1> to client view of cluster
Jan 20, 2017 8:37:02 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server <SERVERIP_1> to client view of cluster
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Jan 20, 2017 8:37:02 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=<SERVERIP_1>, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=<SERVERIP_2>, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=<SERVERIP_3>, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Jan 20, 2017 8:37:03 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server <SERVERIP_1>:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:462)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:205)
 at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:89)
 at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:83)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:43)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
 at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address <RESOLVED_IP_ADDRESSED_MASKED> found
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1497)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
 at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:201)
 ... 7 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address <RESOLVED_IP_ADDRESSED_MASKED> found
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:167)
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:200)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1479)
 ... 16 more

Jan 20, 2017 8:37:03 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server <SERVERIP_1>
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:462)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:205)
 at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:89)
 at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:83)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:43)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
 at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address <RESOLVED_IP_ADDRESSED_MASKED> found
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1497)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
 at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:201)
 ... 7 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address <RESOLVED_IP_ADDRESSED_MASKED> found
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:167)
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:200)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1479)
 ... 16 more

Jan 20, 2017 8:37:03 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server <SERVERIP_1>
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:462)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:205)
 at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:89)
 at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:83)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:43)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
 at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address <RESOLVED_IP_ADDRESSED_MASKED> found
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1497)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
 at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75)
 at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:201)
 ... 7 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address <RESOLVED_IP_ADDRESSED_MASKED> found
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:167)
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:200)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1479)
 ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions

1. Have you whitelisted the IP address(s) in the Atlas cluster to which you are trying to connect from?
2. Personally when connecting to my Atlas cluster via java I use:

   MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI();
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
           DB db = mongoClient.getDB("");
3. Are you using the Java driver for MongoDB? If so ensure it is 3.4.2 and that you are running on Java 8.